# Make a table header fixed with varying number of columns & column-widths using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make a table header fixed on a table having a dynamic number of columns and varying column widths using CSS?

I realize this could be done with JavaScript, but unfortunately, am working on a platform having no JavaScript scope.

Is there a standard-compliant way to accomplish this with pure CSS?

```css
table{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>lorem</th>
                <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                <th>lorem</th>
                <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                <th>lorem ipsum dolor sit</th>
                <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                <th>lorem</th>
                <th>lorem ipsum</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
                <td>lorem</td>
                <td>$lorem</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_murali/39ct0ndb/)

Comment: Can you show us your table markup?

Comment: Table based layout is an old trend, so move up with Div based HTML5. In HTML5 div based you can do easily https://www.developphp.com/video/CSS/Fixed-Header-and-Footer-Div-Layout-Tutorial

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_murali/39ct0ndb/

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Table isn't used for layout here. Use of thead and th indicates OP uses it for displaying tabular data. Also HTML5 isn't about div but main, section, article, header, footer, nav and aside. Also div, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
thead{
  position:fixed;
  background:#fff;
  z-index:0;
}
tbody{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-999;
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to align 'th' and its corresponding 'td' data in a column?